# How to write gsub with curly quotes for UTF-8 strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicode, utf-8, ruby-1.9.2

I am writing an extension method for the String class to clean up non-ASCII characters. The strings that I am cleaning are UTF-8.

When using non-ASCII characters in a file, the console will not start because it is interpreting the curly quotes as regular quotes.

How to escape the curly quote in gsub?

How to write a gsub that uses the unicode for curly quotes (U+201C, for example).

Working in Rails 3.07 and Ruby 1.9.2.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the same `\u` escapes in regexes that you'd use in double quoted strings:

```
s.gsub(/[\u201c\u201d]/, '"')
```

For example:

```
>> s = "\u201Cpancakes\u201d"
=> "“pancakes”"
>> puts s.gsub(/[\u201c\u201d]/, '"')
"pancakes"
```

Comment: @BSeven: That gives me an "out of char range" error in 1.9.2 and 1.9.3. That should be the same as `s.gsub("\u201c", '"')`.

Comment: @BSeven: I need to use `8220.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)` to get `chr` to behave sensibly.

Comment: For reference, same solution but for single quotes:`s.gsub(/[\u2018\u2019]/, '\'')`